# i'm getting this erreur with my metamask, RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error

Tags: metamask, ethereumjs, ganache

I am getting this error when i trying to use metamask on my gancache local for a simple transaction
Metamask is connected to my ganache
this is the erreur [image]

and this is how i called my methode

```
packItem: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var processId = parseInt($(event.target).data('id'));

    App.contracts.SupplyChain.deployed().then(function (instance) {
        return instance.packItem(App.upc, { from: App.metamaskAccountID });
    }).then(function (result) {
        $("#ftc-item").text(result);
        console.log('packItem', result);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    });
},
```

Comment: Looks like the smart contract is returning an error?

Comment: @yangli-io no it's a metmask erreur , i run a test for my smart contract and everything works fine

Comment: Are you authenticating from metamask before calling any method? Look like you have multiple account in metamask and stuck with wrong authentication

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong account to access "this item". this has nothing to do with Metamask or any code error.

you simply don't have the rights for a specific item on the smart contract you are calling and the contract is reverting the transaction with the error you are seeing.

It looks like a code error because web3 or the lib you are using, handles all transaction errors the same, whether it's underfunding or bad data or general assertions in the smart contract, all the same way.

Comment: exactly. apart from network configuration issues and insufficient token balance, this happens because of "require()" function in Solidity. If the condition is not satisfied, as we know, the contract reverts the transaction.